# Cannot pass the POST request to Find query of mongolite and it returns null

Tags: r, api, lubridate, jsonlite, mongolite

```
library(jsonlite)
library(mongolite)
library(lubridate)

#' @post /predict

  predict= function(x, y)
    {
            
    mongodatas <- mongo(collection='db12', url='mongodb://ganesh123:ganesh123456789@ds263137.mlab.com:63137/ganesh123')

    naan <- mongodatas$find(query= '{ "data_time":  {"$gte": "x" , "$lt": "y"} }',
                          fields= '{"_id": 0, "data_time": 1, "id": 1, "sensor3": 1 }',
                          sort=  '{"data_time": 1}' ,
                          limit=5000
                          )

    return(naan)

  }
```

The above code is my R Api done using plumber and done using POST method and this works if the below postman input `x` and `y` is given as static in the find query

```
naan <- mongodatas$find(query= '{ "data_time":  {"$gte": **"x"** , "$lt": **"y"**} }',  "

    {
        
    "x": "2018-07-25 17:02:17.249591",
    "y": "2018-07-25 17:02:17.674801"
        
}
```

The above code is my input to R Api
This is input from postman link http://localhost:3000/predict

```
 "id": "1",
 "data_time": "2018-07-25 17:02:17.249591",
 "sensor3": "4.12"
```

This is my database structure. The query cannot process the input data.

Comment: not sure if u can use x and y from post directly like this.. u need to extract the data from req$postBody (assume u r passing this json in the post body). Also, mongo query is wrong bcz u r not passing x and y as variables there.. u need to first come up with the query by using paste0 and then pass it to the find function from mongolite. Bcz at the moment ur query is assuming date_time in "x" and "y" and not their values

Comment: use sprintf for creating the query using parameters. ```> sprintf('{ "data_time":  {"$gte": "%s" , "$lt": "%s"} }', 'date1', 'date2')
[1] "{ \"data_time\":  {\"$gte\": \"date1\" , \"$lt\": \"date2\"} }"```

Comment: can you provide some example because the sprintf query return empty array and also how to send the values of x and y

Comment: can you provide the correct code of above because i tried in both the method you specified

Comment: Thank you Akshay bro your query works with slight modification. .                       sprintf('{ "data_time": {"$gte": "%s" , "$lt": "%s"} }', date1, date2)      thank you so much

Comment: Cool happy to help!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).